# object is not recognised in a Linq statement allthough in the same method the object is accessable

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object **"word"** in a Linq Statement (see: "**from bee in world.Bees"**) that is not recognized although in the same method the object is recognized in the previous row.  I don't now why this is happening. I'm using the word object everywhere in my code without problem. I've made some comments to the code to highlight the problem...

**Here are the relevant code fragments:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private World word;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        word = new World(new BeeMessage(SendMessage)); // BeeMessage is a delegate
        .......
    }

    private void SendMessage(int ID, string Message)
    {
        int count = word.Bees.Count; //this line works !! now error message            
        // LinQ selection
        var beeGroups =
          from bee in world.Bees        // The item word does not exists in the current context
          group bee by bee.CurrentState into beeGroup
          orderby beeGroup.Key
          select beeGroup;
          ..............
    }
[Serializable]
class World
{              
    public List<Bee> Bees;
    ......
}
```

Comment: This Bee world sounds intriguing...

Comment: in the Word object it is a field: public List<Bee> Bees;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have got a mistake here.

change your variable world to word here

```
 from bee in world.Bees
```

to

```
from bee in word.Bees
```

Comment: The Class named World not Word

Comment: @Chris : Thanks, I have mistyped the variable name at the beginning  of the form. This has solved the problem  !

Answer (score 5):

your variable is `word`, you put `world`

```
 from bee in world.Bees //should be word.Bees
```

Note: Personally I would refactor your `word` variable to be `world`... (To do this right click on word an choose Refactor > rename)